# Is For loop the best way to check if Cell IsNumeric?

Tags: excel, vba

I have to do a VBA code that check if the Cells in Column "A" IsNumber. I work with sheets that have 2k ~ 3k rows per table.

I wanna know if a For loop thru the cells in the range, is the best **Optimal** way to do this.

```
Dim tmpCell as Range

For each tmpCell in Range("A1:B5").Columns(1)
    If IsNumeric(tmpCell) = True Then
        tmpCell = tmpCell.Value*1
    End if
next tmpCell
```

**I need to verify if the cell is Number, because when I paste the info from a Pivot Table, one column is copied as string, not number.**

[image: Warning Box: This Cell is a String, convert to Number]

Thank you, for your time.

Edit:
My table is something like this.

The numbers in the "A" Column is in string, not number.

```
 |  A1  | B1 | C1 |
1| 1234 | 1  | 2  |
2| 5678 | 2  | 4  |
3| 9012 | 3  | 5  |
4|Total | 5  | 11 |
```

Comment: You can use text to columns to do this in one step.

Comment: `Range("A1:B5").Columns(1).Value = Range("A1:B5").Columns(1).Value`?

Comment: Hi, @ScottCraner. Could you teach how i do this? Thank you, mate.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I have the last row as Total Line. So if a multiply "Total" by 1, to convert as number, i get the `#VALUE!` warning.

Comment: My suggestion doesn't include multiplying. You use it just as it is: one line (instead of your complete code), that's all.